# Victory-native: Change background behind label

Tags: tailwind-css, victory-charts, victory-native

I want to change the color of the background behind the label. I've tried changing it in the view component where we use tailwind. I have also tried to simply check if Victory-native have anything that could help me with that.

I managed to create [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMbp2.jpg) in my app

But I really want it to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMyOB.png)

Hope anyone could help me with this or point me in the right direction:))

```
<View style={tw`bg-orange-100 rounded-2xl mb-3 mr-5 w-${size} h-45 p-[0px]`}>
        <View style={tw`self-center`}>
          <VictoryChart height={190} width={350}>
            <VictoryAxis
              style={{
                axis: { stroke: 'transparent' },
                ticks: { stroke: 'transparent' },
                tickLabels: { fill: 'white' },
              }}
            />
            <VictoryGroup offset={20}>
              <VictoryStack>
                <VictoryBar
                  data={usage}
                  cornerRadius={{ top: 9}}
                  style={{ data: { fill: '#FF9B68' } }}
                />
                <VictoryBar
                  data={estimate}
                  cornerRadius={{ top: 9}}
                  style={{ data: { fill: '#FFC9AD' } }}
                />
              </VictoryStack>
            </VictoryGroup>
          </VictoryChart>
        </View>
      </View>
    </>
```

Comment: Share your code of what you've tried ?

Comment: @mohitmaroliya Sorry about that, I've done it now. I'm new to Stackoverflow